# Downloading a file from JFrog Artifactory using its URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, artifactory

I'm using JFrog Artifactory and want to download file using C# and WebClient. The URL is like /filename.zip

But it downloads as a HTML page. Says container is damaged. And also the HTML says "you needs to enable JavaScript".

How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Can you provide specific errors regarding container damage? Or show us your code, it will help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [Retrieve Folder or Repository Archive API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveFolderorRepositoryArchive) allows to download an archive file (supports zip/tar/tar.gz/tgz) containing all the artifacts that reside under the specified path (folder or repository root). However it does not support filtering by properties.

The [Artifactory CLI](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-cli-go) supports concurrently downloading multiple files. It also supports downloading files we matches a set of property values. The CLI, however, will use multiple HTTP requests for doing so.

A third option would be developing a custom [user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins) which allows downloading an archive of artifacts matching a set of properties. An execution user plugin can be [executed](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ExecutePluginCode) as a REST API call. There is a [sample plugin](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/download/downloadDirectoryContent) in the JFrogDev GitHub account which can serve as a good start point. This plugin allows downloading the content of a directory as an archive.